# Enable audio over HDMI on Raspbian Jessie with AV Receiver

Tags: audio, hdmi, pi-zero, pi-zero-w

I am attempting to connect a Raspberry Pi Zero W with HDMI to an AV Receiver (Pioneer VSX-820).  My interest is exclusively in playing sound over the speakers connected to the receiver, although there is also a television connected to the receiver.  Unfortunately, I am not getting any sound.

I am plugging the pi into an HDMI port labeled "BD."  I have verified that if I plug my DVD player into the BD port I can get audio.  I've also verified that if I plug the pi into my TV's HDMI port I can get audio through the TV from the pi.

This seems to rule out anything being wrong with the ports, cables, or hardware.

Is there some unique configuration that is required to get audio with an AV Receiver?

Comment: It...er...eventually started working.  I haven't figured out why, yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want 100% understand what went on here, but it briefly started working again, possibly because I plugged the pi directly into the TV and then moved it over to the receiver.  While it was working, I dumped the edid with:

```
tvservice -d edid.dat
```

Eventually (probably after a reboot) it stopped working again.

Then I moved edid.dat to the /boot/ directory (with the name edid.dat), opened /boot/config.txt, and added the line:

```
hdmi_edid_file = 1
```

Then a quick reboot, and everything *seems* to be working.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Comment: Hi Will. Thanks for this information, because I’m considering a very similar setup to yours. Can you share the EDID file and also maybe confirm that this hack is working stably? I do not have an HDMI+audio-enabled video device, only the A/V receiver.

Comment: @JonasSchäfer I don't think my edid file would be helpful to you.  However, I have been using this solution for two years now without any issues, so I can confirm that this hack is as stable as anything else I've ever done with a computer :)

Comment: @Will Thanks for the reply. FWIW, I ran some tests, and even without a TV attached, the audio playback via the A/V receiver works without any issues on my Pi 2B.